# How can I back up my boot drive?

Tags: backup

I am running XBMC on an Ubuntu minimal install. There is no desktop environment installed. Is there a way I can clone my boot drive to a USB drive so that it can be restored at a later date if needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparison of backup tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) is great utility to do backup and cloning. It is pre installed on Ubuntu. 
You can take backup of live server either on local server or on remote server.

For example

```
rync <source> <destionation>
```

following command will backup my all Ubuntu root partition to my remote server (192.168.1.55).

```
rsync root@kk:/  root@192.168.1.55:/backup_kk
```

Another Technique to clone server is take snapshot of root partition of server with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), But it requires to reboot server. Your partition must be unmounted at that time.

Comment: Clonezilla looks like it'll do the trick, thanks